# npz file as input in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to wrap a npz file with pybind11. I have the following arguments in python, where the function pathlookup is in c++ :

```
import testpy_path
sourcefile1 = np.load('data1.npy')
sourcefile2 = np.load('data2.npz') 
testpy_path.pathlookup(sourcefile1, sourcefile2) //error at sourcefile2
```

In C++ with pybind11, I'm trying to generate the numpy inputs sourcefile1 and sourcefile2 like this:

```
void pathlookup(py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style | py::array::forecast> sourcefile1, py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style | py::array::forecast> sourcefile2){
    std::vector<double> sources1(sourcefile1.size()); 
    std::memcpy(sources1.data(), sourcefile1.data(), sourcefile1.size() * sizeof(double)); 
}
```

It works fine with sourcefile1 the .npy file but it doesn't work with the numpy .npz file. My question is, what are the arguments needed in the function pathlookup c++ to use the npz file and how would I store the npz file into a vector?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very experienced with `numpy`, but this is what I found in the manual:

When you use `load()` with `npz` files then `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile` instance is created, that's not an `array` instance. Here is important part from manual about `NpzFile`:

> A dictionary-like object with lazy-loading of files in the zipped archive provided on construction.

> NpzFile is used to load files in the NumPy .npz data archive format. It assumes that files in the archive have a .npy extension, other files are ignored.

> The arrays and file strings are lazily loaded on either getitem access using obj['key'] or attribute lookup using obj.f.key. A list of all files (without .npy extensions) can be obtained with obj.files and the ZipFile object itself using obj.zip.

That means you access your arrays through:

```
np.savez("out.npz", x=data)
x = np.load("out.npz")['x']
```

Then `x` can be passed to your function.

https://www.kite.com/python/docs/numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile

**Edit:**

If you wish to load numpy arrays directly through `pybind` you can do:

```
auto np = py::module::import("numpy");
py::dict d = np.attr("load")("out.npz");
for(auto k : d)
{
    std::cout << k.first.cast<std::string>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << k.second.cast<py::array>().size() << std::endl;
}
```

or pass npz file handle as `dict`.

Comment: yes I know, my question was how would I import a npy file into c++ using pybind11?

Comment: @Mimi I edited the answer, you can pass it as a `py::dict`.